# Python: pandas, importing a single column, as a list

Tags: python, list, csv

I'm trying to export data from a csv file into list.
It's a list of wines and their colour
But when I test if an element is in the list I'm getting a false negative. 
When I examine the list, I *think* I've accidently created a nested list

My question is, what change should I make so that I just get a list of the wines.

```
with open('colour_red.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig', errors='ignore') as f:
    red_reader = csv.reader(f)
    wine_list_red = list(red_reader)
```

If I print a single element I get:

```
[['Agni', 'R']]
```

If I print the whole list I get:

```
[['Prime_variety', 'Colour'],
 ['Abondant', 'W'],
 ['Afus Ali', 'W'],
 ['Agadai', 'W'],
 ['Airen', 'W'],
 ['Alarije', 'W'],...]
```

Second Q: how come if I run this I get false.

```
if 'Abondant' in wine_list_red:
        print('True') 
    else:
        print('False')
```

Comment: Hi, Have you considered using pandas dataframe. It would be much simpler to do what you are attempting here.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list like:

```
original_list = [['Prime_variety', 'Colour'],
 ['Abondant', 'W'],
 ['Afus Ali', 'W'],
 ['Agadai', 'W'],
 ['Airen', 'W'],
 ['Alarije', 'W'],...]
```

and you want the list of wines only, you can do:

```
wine_list = [x[0] for x in original_list if x[0] != "Prime_variety"]

>>> 'Abondant' in wine_list
True
```

You can rather use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("colour_red.csv")
print(df["Prime_variety"].tolist())
```

Comment: `pandas` is definitely the most correct solution to this problem

Answer (score 0):

When you read the file with the csv reader, it already creates this as a list. By adding the list command (`wine_list_red = list(red_reader)`), you create the nested list.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

> Each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings. No automatic data type conversion is performed unless the QUOTE_NONNUMERIC format option is specified (in which case unquoted fields are transformed into floats).

Your second question is related to the first, `in` does not unpack the nested layers of the list. This means that when you use `in`, you're searching for a string `"Wine Variety"` against a all of the lists which are represented as `["Wine Variety"]` which is causing your if statement to fail.

Finally, I've noticed you've tagged your question as pandas but you aren't actually using pandas. Pandas is a good approach because it simplifies a lot of the details behind this and you can use a `pd.read_csv(filename)` to take care of most of your code